# Duplicate photos on iOS when changing aspect ratio

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, photos

When I change the aspect ratio from 4:3 to 16:9 and I take a photo, iOS 16.4 will save two images in the mobile storage, one for 4:3 and another one for 16:9. I could visualize this "normal behavior" using Windows 10 from File Explorer.

Is it happens to do the same to you ?

You can only see the duplicates accessing a file viewer; using iTunes or Gallery in iOS will show you as it as one photo taken, but in the storage there is for two! One is called `IMG_[number]` and the other one as it was edited `IMG_E[number]`

If you keep 4:3 then only one photo is taken, so I presume this is the default image that is editing after.

Comment: Does the photos you changed the ratio appear in Photos > Utilities > Duplicates? Also, what have you done to change the size?

Comment: No, they are not showing in Duplicates either. I simply change the option from Camera, you can change to 16:9 or square or 4:3

Comment: Ok, then, try taking a photo with 4:3 and then **Edit** it and from there resize it to the 16:9 : when editing : click on this button ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSnMH.jpg ), then, click on this button ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4h5u.jpg ).  Then, at the bottom of your screen, you should see options to set the size of the image, click on "16:9".
The links are links to images of the buttons.

Comment: One is the original, the other the edit. It will always keep the original in case you ever want to revert. macOS & iOS will hide this from you to save clutter. Windows doesn't know how to do this. File Explorer is a very crude way to see into the DCIM folder, which Mac users don't have to suffer.

Comment: But I didn't edit the photo, that is my concern. Of course I could do your way, but why they've put this selection option directly from the camera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone is capturing the image at the native aspect ratio. The software is changing to the selected aspect ratio. Apple implements this as an edit and made the decision to save the original as well as the "edit". There is no setting to turn this off (as many would prefer, especially when making an artistic decision to shoot at a specific ratio or with another effect). Some Apple software hides this from the user, but both files exist.

There are many discussions about this topic on Apple community forums.

Comment: I've also asked on Apple community forum too but no relevant answer given:  
`We reviewed the information in iPhone camera basics and we're not seeing any indication that more than one photo is saved when taking photos in 16:9 aspect ratios. 
With that in mind, we'd recommend contacting Apple Support for additional help with this. They'll be best equipped to take a closer look and provide any available solutions.` 
and guess what, the "Senior Support Specialist" didn't know about it and said to me there is no duplication from their side !!! they think us morons or what ?